# Rainmeter Gmail WebParser failing

Tags: rainmeter

Rainmeter Gmail path pattern is like so

`https://[your Gmail user name]:­[your Gmail password]@gmail.google.com/­gmail/­feed/atom`

yet i put my credentials in specified locations in RainMeter (all themes are the same end result for me) and I am getting a fatal error. Does this have to do with special characters in the password field? I've tried encoding them myself such as space is %20 and so on. any ideas why the feed is not coming through

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm "a bit" late, but I will answer anyway. From my experience, you need to create a password for app (in this case, the web parser) from Gmail control panel. How to do this [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en). After that, you should be done.